# How do I remove excess rows to make rows filled

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to remove the extra rows:

[image]

To:

[image]

I need to be able to dynamically do this, I cannot explicilty do the below as my last row changes.:

```
Rows(44).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(45).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(46).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: This feels like you question is not how to remove them (you showed you know how to delete row) but how to identify the rows which should be deleted.

Comment: correct, i can work it better

Comment: You should clarify: what are the conditions for a row to be deleted?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that when you delete row 44, row 46 becomes row 45, and so on, so delete them in reverse to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dim last as long
last = Range("B" & rows.count).End(XlUp).Row + 1
Rows(last & ":" & rows.count).Delete
```

last finds the last used rows, whereafter the delete statements deletes all rows from there to the end